# The domain "or.sstatic.net" seems flaky: I'm seeing a lot of packet loss

Tags: support, cdn

I'm seeing a lot of packet loss around HE/peak while attempting to get to `or.sstatic.net`:

```
 1. 172.14.17.1                                              0.0%    71    2.2   2.3   2.1   3.6   0.2
 2. lns20.syd7.internode.on.net                              0.0%    71   28.8  29.1  27.2  37.0   1.5
 3. te3-3.cor2.syd7.internode.on.net                         0.0%    71   28.8  30.7  26.7  71.7   6.2
 4. gi6-0-0-108.bdr1.syd7.internode.on.net                   0.0%    71  186.7 198.6 185.9 430.6  40.5
 5. pos2-0.bdr1.sjc2.internode.on.net                        0.0%    70  186.4 186.9 184.8 192.6   1.7
 6. 10gigabitethernet2-3.core1.sjc2.he.net                   0.0%    70  210.3 214.7 209.1 222.0   3.6
 7. 10gigabitethernet1-1.core1.pdx1.he.net                   0.0%    70  202.2 205.0 200.0 212.4   3.5
 8. peak-internet-llc.gigabitethernet2-1.core1.pdx1.he.net   81.2%    70  699.2 689.9 665.3 707.0  12.5
 9. ge-0-0-2-cvo-br1.peak.org                                81.2%    70  716.4 714.6 695.6 725.7   8.2
10. ge-1-0-0-cvo-core2.peak.org                              81.2%    70  709.5 700.0 685.7 719.9   9.5
11. 69.59.218.226                                            81.2%    70  715.8 719.3 697.6 731.6  10.4
12. sstatic.net                                              78.3%    70  712.6 717.2 699.3 742.3  11.3
```

This is causing problems mainly on chat; I'm not sure why nothing else is having problems.  Anyone else seeing this behaviour?

Comment: Mostly everything else relies on the CDNs and the NY data center. The PEAK website is non-responsive, so I'm guessing their Oregon data center is experiencing issues at the moment (I also noticed the high packet loss).

Comment: Something similar has been reported by a couple of our users in the UK recently. Are you located there as well?

Comment: No, Sydney Australia.  Sorry, I thought the mtr output was more informative than it actually is.

Answer (score 4):

We have seen a lot of reports of the same thing from our monitoring system and have asked Peak about this.  I will update this after we have an answer or know more.